# MediatR setup for shared Class Library in Console vs WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, cqrs, mediatr

I have a .Net Core 2.2 class library that uses the CQRS pattern with MediatR. I add all my dependencies into a serviceProvider in Main and attach MediatR via:

```
serviceCollection.AddMediatR();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Everything works like a charm and I am able to send any of my commands or queries to MediatR without fail.

I want to use the same exact library in a WebApi (also .Net Core 2.2) and set up my serviceProvider the exact same way inside of the **Startup.ConfigureServices()** method and I get the following exception when calling any controller that uses MediatR:

> InvalidOperationException: Handler was not found for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Core.Application.Accounts.Queries.GetAccountListQuery,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.Application.Accounts.Models.AccountViewModel]]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.
>   MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerBase.GetHandler(ServiceFactory factory)

I was able to resolve the issue by explicitly adding each command or query prior to adding MediatR to the DI container:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetAccountListQuery).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
services.AddMediatR();
```

But does this mean I have to register every single **IRequest** object in my library? How is **MediatR** able to register them for me in the **Console** app but not in the **WebAPI**? Is there a better method?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876478/autofac-mediatr-multiple-dll-projects) that recommends assembly scanning, however it ***perplexes*** me that my Console app seemed to do this automatically. Also I am not sure I want to move to **Autofac** just yet. I have seen some packages to help you do the same with the default ServiceProvider - however I really want to avoid adding extra dependencies unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: In my project I simply have:

     services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetAccountListQuery)); 

and nothing more.
Tried your way and also worked for me.    
Think we need more information about the way your project is setup.
Is it several projects?

Comment: Understood - however how I register them is not the issue. I will be potentially be having hundreds of commands/queries and I want to add them to MediatR without having to register each one in every entry point. I'm also curious why Console does not require any registration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be enough to just have this:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetAccountListQuery));
```

or just

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
```

It works for me in `ASP.NET Core` 2.2. The project has these two `NuGet` dependencies:

- [`MediatR`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR/) version 6.0.0
- [`MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) version 6.0.1

P.S. For those, who minuses - any class from assembly would work. I used `GetAccountListQuery` as an example because it is for sure inside the right assembly. See my comments below.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. However as I will be potentially be having hundreds of commands/queries I want to add them to MediatR without having to register each one in every entry point. I'm also curious why Console does not require any registration.

Comment: You can use ANY of classes from assembly where `MediatR` should find the commands. Never underestimate the power of reading the official documentation ;)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I tried just using services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup)); but I still get the 'Handler was not found' exception. I also tried using the name of the class library that the Commands are in but every namespace path I use gives me a '...is a namespace but is used like a type' error. It only resolves down to each command - which brings me right back to having to register each one again.

Comment: Strange! I tried just adding ONE of the commands and the rest resolved automatically. Seems like that did the trick. But it also seems like an odd way to add a class library to MediatR!

Comment: That might be strange, but works. If you are curious why - you could go to source code for `MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` and figure out what is happening behind the scene. Anyway I was glad to help.